# how to get nested observable objects

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I am working on the angular 4  application plus rxjs 5.x.

The json data structure like following.

Please anyone let me know how to get all the students list for class id NOT equal to 1 by rxjs operators.

Thanks

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "class": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "English"
    },
    "students": [
      {
        "student": {
          "id": 101,
          "name": "hi101",
          "email": "hi101@marr.com.au"
        }
      },
      {
        "student": {
          "id": 102,
          "name": "hi101",
          "email": "hi101@marr.com.au"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "class": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Physics"
    },
    "students": [
      {
        "student": {
          "id": 201,
          "name": "ph201",
          "email": "ph201@marr.com.au"
        }
      },
      {
        "student": {
          "id": 202,
          "name": "ph202",
          "email": "ph202@marr.com.au"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "class": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Maths"
    },
    "students": [
      {
        "student": {
          "id": 301,
          "name": "m301",
          "email": "m301@marr.com.au"
        }
      },
      {
        "student": {
          "id": 302,
          "name": "m302",
          "email": "m302@marr.com.au"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: use filter u just have to itereate over every object https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#filter

Comment: Thanks Panos K,  I got it as following code.  
        entities.filter(x => x.id !== filterState.selectedClassId)
        .map(x => x.students)
        .reduce(function(pre, cur) {
          return pre.concat(cur);
        })
        .map(result => {
          return result.student;
        });